# How To Check When Curl PID is Done from Bash Loop

Tags: bash, curl, background-process

I can't figure out my bug on OSX. When I try to see when Curl is finished, the process remains loaded. I never see the CURL FINISHED message.

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -S -o example.com http://example.com/downloads/example.zip &
CURL_PID=$!
echo -e "CURL PID = $CURL_PID"
while :
do
    sleep 1
    if [ -n $(ps -p$CURL_PID -o pid=) ]; then
        echo "CURL NOT FINISHED"
    else
      echo "CURL FINISHED"
      break
    fi
done
```

Note on OSX's version of Bash when I run this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PIDX=1
if [ -n $(ps -p$PIDX -o pid=) ]; then
  echo "PROCESS 1 IS THERE"
else
  echo "PROCESS 1 IS NOT THERE"
fi
```

...it says Process 1 is there. (Everyone has a PID 1, so this is just an example.) So, I know that my `if` statement is correct. No double quotes necessary on the `if` line.

Note that I can't use wait on the `$CURL_PID` because what you don't see here is that I also am using OSX's `osascript` command to show a dialog that says "Downloading...", which also has a Cancel button on it and its own `$DLG_PID`, and so I'm looping endlessly until either they cancel the dialog (meaning `$DLG_PID` points is gone) or `$CURL_PID` is gone (meaning the download finally completed so I can run `kill $DLG_PID` now).

On OSX, note I'm doing this as well before the `curl` statement.

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Downloading..." with title "My App Installer" buttons {"Cancel"}' &
```

So, if someone cancels the dialog, I kill the curl by PID and exit the infinite loop (and exit the bash script). If they don't cancel that dialog, and the curl finishes, then I kill the dialog by PID and exit the bash script.

Comment: First, the phrase "Bash bug" doesn't mean what you probably want it to mean... Secondly, what's that shebang? `#!` please. Thirdly, `$(ps blah)` needs to be quoted. Once you quote it, it should run just fine. Fourth, the way you check if curl has finished is just horrible. What if a new process with the same pid sprang up between your two checks (albeit 1s is relatively short)? Not to mention it's extremely clumsy. Just let `curl` run synchronously, or at least use the `wait` builtin.

Comment: Okay, I adjusted some of this. However, note that there's more to this. I'm showing on OSX with the osascript command a dialog that says "Downloading..." and has a Cancel button on it, and I have that PID as well. So, if they cancel that, then in my while loop I check for that too. That's why I can't use wait.

Comment: Regarding your edit: you claim that your `if` statement is correct, and you give a simple example, but your simple example is wrong in exactly the same way. You always get a false sense of correctness when your `then` branch works; why don't you test the `else` branch, which is why you don't see `CURL FINISHED`? Compare `if [ -n $(:) ]; then echo nonempty; else echo empty; fi` and `if [ -n "$(:)" ]; then echo nonempty; else echo empty; fi`.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I think you're on to something here. I'm needing to put doublequotes around the $(...) stuff. Checking now...brb...

Comment: @4ae1e1 That fixed it. I was missing doublequotes around the $(...) stuff.

Comment: @4ae1e1 I look forward to seeing your answer in the answer section, especially with an example of `kill -0 %1`. Note in my case, I show a modeless dialog as a background process, then kickoff the curl as a background process, then loop until either the modeless dialog is cancelled, or curl finishes. If curl finishes, I kill the dialog by its pid.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake; using stored pid from the parent process (instead of job control) is safe after all. Anyway, one should still poll with the `kill` builtin instead of a complicated `ps` call which is not even portable. Will write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The portable way for polling a backgrounded job is to use the `kill` builtin, and send the signal `0` to see if it's deliverable. `kill -0 $pid` (where `$pid` is the PID of a child process) will return zero if the child process is still running, and nonzero if it has already died. Note that this is safe and *only* safe (from PID recycling) for a child process (rather than some random process started elsewhere, with PID written to a PID file), for reasons outlined [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#PIDs_and_parents):

> Each UNIX process also has a parent process. This parent process is the process that started it, but can change to the init process if the parent process ends before the new process does. (That is, `init` will pick up orphaned processes.) Understanding this parent/child relationship is vital because it is the key to reliable process management in UNIX. A process's PID will NEVER be freed up for use after the process dies UNTIL the parent process waits for the PID to see whether it ended and retrieve its exit code. If the parent ends, the process is returned to `init`, which does this for you.
>
> This is important for one major reason: if the parent process manages its child process, it can be absolutely certain that, even if the child process dies, no other new process can accidentally recycle the child process's PID until the parent process has waited for that PID and noticed the child died. This gives the parent process the guarantee that the PID it has for the child process will ALWAYS point to that child process, whether it is alive or a "zombie". Nobody else has that guarantee.

Of course, newer versions of OS X don't use `init` (in its place is `launchd`), but the principle is the same.

By the way, the whole page is worth a read: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement.

In light of that, here's an example script that does what you want (it takes one URL argument — the URL to download). Bug me if something's unclear.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Downloading..." with title "Downloader" buttons {"Cancel"}' &>/dev/null &
dialog_pid=$!
curl -sSLO "$1" &
curl_pid=$!
timer=0
while kill -0 "$curl_pid" &>/dev/null; do
    kill -0 "$dialog_pid" &>/dev/null || { echo "User cancelled download from dialog."; kill "$curl_pid" &>/dev/null; exit 1; }
    sleep 1
    (( timer++ ))
    echo "Been downloading for $timer seconds..."
done
echo "Finished."
kill "$dialog_pid" &>/dev/null
wait &>/dev/null
```

Run it:

```
> ./download https://github.com/torvalds/linux/archive/v4.4-rc2.tar.gz
Been downloading for 1 seconds...
Been downloading for 2 seconds...
<omitted>
Been downloading for 38 seconds...
Finished.
```

Cancelling midway:

```
> ./download https://github.com/torvalds/linux/archive/v4.4-rc2.tar.gz
Been downloading for 1 seconds...
Been downloading for 2 seconds...
Been downloading for 3 seconds...
User cancelled download from dialog.
```

The ugly thing is that killing the PID of the `osascript` job doesn't dismiss the dialog box... Which I'm not in the position to solve because I absolutely dread AppleScript.

Comment: "The killing of the PID of the osascript job doesn't dismiss the dialog box." I found the fix -- remove 'tell app "System Events" to ' out and then it works. BTW, in my case, I switched this to a Cocoa window drawn with Swift now.

Comment: The thought is crossing my mind, yes. I'm just learning Swift. It's quirky.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you'll use `wait` for that:

```
curl http://... &
do_something
wait
echo "CURL has finished"
```